# How is the second smallest eigenvalue of normalized laplacian bounded for random graphs?

Tags: co.combinatorics, graph-theory, eigenvalues, spectral-graph-theory

It is well known that for any graph G following holds

$\frac{\lambda_2}{2} ≤ \phi(G) ≤ \sqrt{2\lambda_2}$, where $\phi(G)$ is the conductance of the graph and $\lambda_2$ is the second smallest eigenvalue of the normalized laplacian of the graph $G$.

My question is that do we know anything on the upper bound of $\lambda_2$ for random graphs. I believe that there is a theoretical bound on conductance that depends on average degree of the random graph, but I cannot find any literature that directly addresses that. I need a connection between the eigenvalue and average degree of the random graph (also d-regular random graphs are okay) in order to show that.

Thanks.

Comment: Friedman [showed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ramanujan_graph#Ramanujan_graphs_as_expander_graphs) that for every $\epsilon > 0 $ and for sufficiently large $n$, a random $d$-regular $n$-vertex graph G satisfies $\lambda(G)<2\sqrt{d-1}+\epsilon$, and that's the best bound possible for regular graphs of fixed degree $d$.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I suppose we can connect that eigenvalue of adjacency matrix to the normalized laplacian matrix quite easily in case of regular graphs. I will need to get myself more familiar with the proof but thanks again for the ref.